# Can the Telegram bot API play sound from an online audio streaming URL?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

Telegram BOT API has functions to send audio files and documents ,But can it play from an online sound streaming URL?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. 
I use:

```
define('API_URL', 'https://api.telegram.org/bot'.BOT_TOKEN.'/');
$sendto =API_URL."sendmessage?chat_id=".$chatID."&text=".urlencode($url_track);
file_get_contents($sendto);
```

For example in row 74 in https://github.com/Ellusu/Jamendo_SearchBot/blob/master/index.php

Comment: It simply open a stream in the browser.

Comment: I think the asker meant a thing such "unidirectional" voip

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't with Telegram Bot APIs. 
You must download the file and upload it on Telegram servers.

Answer (score 0):

It will just show preview of link and if it's an audio, an audio bar will be shown. so the answer is yes, but it will not start automatically and user should download and play it.

Answer (score 0):

The userbot [VoiceChatStreamer](https://pythonawesome.com/this-bot-can-stream-audio-or-video-files-and-urls-in-telegram-voice-chats/) claims to allow exactly that.